# Google Maps Embed + Search box

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to make a map for my website, that will show a few markers of restaurants. 
I would also like people to be able to search the map, so they can look for an address and would be able to see the restaurants in that area. 
I got a code for the map with markers like i want it:

```
 <script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&sensor=false&extension=.js'></script> 

<script> 
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
    var map;
    function init() {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.142265,11.577987),
            zoom: 12,
            zoomControl: true,
            zoomControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.DEFAULT,
            },
            disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            scaleControl: false,
            scrollwheel: true,
            panControl: true,
            streetViewControl: false,
            draggable : true,
            overviewMapControl: false,
            overviewMapControlOptions: {
                opened: false,
            },
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            styles: [
    {
        "featureType": "water",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "on"
            },
            {
                "color": "#b5cbe4"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "landscape",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#efefef"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#83a5b0"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.arterial",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#bdcdd3"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.local",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#ffffff"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "poi.park",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#e3eed3"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "administrative",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "on"
            },
            {
                "lightness": 33
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road"
    },
    {
        "featureType": "poi.park",
        "elementType": "labels",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "on"
            },
            {
                "lightness": 20
            }
        ]
    },
    {},
    {
        "featureType": "road",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "lightness": 20
            }
        ]
    }
],
        }
        var mapElement = document.getElementById('restaurantmap');
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);
        var locations = [
['blahfl', 'falfjlfs', '9480240', 'undefined', 'www.google.com', 48.1303358, 11.5911791, 'https://mapbuildr.com/assets/img/markers/solid-pin-blue.png'],['fahfah', 'ljlsg', '2742470', 'undefined', 'www.google.com', 48.1367075, 11.5556444, 'https://mapbuildr.com/assets/img/markers/solid-pin-green.png']
        ];
        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            if (locations[i][1] =='undefined'){ description ='';} else { description = locations[i][1];}
            if (locations[i][2] =='undefined'){ telephone ='';} else { telephone = locations[i][2];}
            if (locations[i][3] =='undefined'){ email ='';} else { email = locations[i][3];}
           if (locations[i][4] =='undefined'){ web ='';} else { web = locations[i][4];}
           if (locations[i][7] =='undefined'){ markericon ='';} else { markericon = locations[i][7];}
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                icon: markericon,
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][5], locations[i][6]),
                map: map,
                title: locations[i][0],
                desc: description,
                tel: telephone,
                email: email,
                web: web
            });
if (web.substring(0, 7) != "http://") {
link = "http://" + web;
} else {
link = web;
}
            bindInfoWindow(marker, map, locations[i][0], description, telephone, email, web, link);
     }
 function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, title, desc, telephone, email, web, link) {
      var infoWindowVisible = (function () {
              var currentlyVisible = false;
              return function (visible) {
                  if (visible !== undefined) {
                      currentlyVisible = visible;
                  }
                  return currentlyVisible;
               };
           }());
           iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
           google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
               if (infoWindowVisible()) {
                   iw.close();
                   infoWindowVisible(false);
               } else {
                   var html= "<div style='color:#000;background-color:#fff;padding:5px;width:150px;'><h4>"+title+"</h4><p>"+desc+"<p><p>"+telephone+"<p><a href='"+link+"'' >"+web+"<a></div>";
                   iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:html});
                   iw.open(map,marker);
                   infoWindowVisible(true);
               }
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(iw, 'closeclick', function () {
            infoWindowVisible(false);
        });
 }
}
</script>
<style>
    #restaurantmap {
        height:400px;
        width:550px;
    }
    .gm-style-iw * {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .gm-style-iw h4, .gm-style-iw p {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .gm-style-iw a {
        color: #4272db;
    }
</style>

<div id='restaurantmap'></div>
```

and I found this code to add the search box (with autocomplete which is important to me):
https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox

But I can't seem to figure out how to mix the two together to make them work together. My coding knowledge is still very limited :(

I would really appreciate your help!

Thank you

Comment: What does your code look like where you tried to add the search functionality?  Did you remember to include the places library?

Comment: Hi geocodezip, 
I don't actually know where to add the search box (which is in the link I put in my question) in to the main map code... could you explain where it's supposed to go? and what is the places library? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [documentation for SearchBox](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#places_searchbox)
- [documentation for places library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places)

Include the places library like this:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
```

working code snippet:

```js
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
var map;
var markers = [];

function init() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.142265, 11.577987),
    zoom: 12,
    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.DEFAULT,
    },
    disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    scaleControl: false,
    scrollwheel: true,
    panControl: true,
    streetViewControl: false,
    draggable: true,
    overviewMapControl: false,
    overviewMapControlOptions: {
      opened: false,
    },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    styles: [{
      "featureType": "water",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "on"
      }, {
        "color": "#b5cbe4"
      }]
    }, {
      "featureType": "landscape",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#efefef"
      }]
    }, {
      "featureType": "road.highway",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#83a5b0"
      }]
    }, {
      "featureType": "road.arterial",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#bdcdd3"
      }]
    }, {
      "featureType": "road.local",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#ffffff"
      }]
    }, {
      "featureType": "poi.park",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#e3eed3"
      }]
    }, {
      "featureType": "administrative",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "on"
      }, {
        "lightness": 33
      }]
    }, {
      "featureType": "road"
    }, {
      "featureType": "poi.park",
      "elementType": "labels",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "on"
      }, {
        "lightness": 20
      }]
    }, {}, {
      "featureType": "road",
      "stylers": [{
        "lightness": 20
      }]
    }],
  }
  var mapElement = document.getElementById('restaurantmap');
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);
  var locations = [
    ['blahfl', 'falfjlfs', '9480240', 'undefined', 'www.google.com', 48.1303358, 11.5911791, 'https://mapbuildr.com/assets/img/markers/solid-pin-blue.png'],
    ['fahfah', 'ljlsg', '2742470', 'undefined', 'www.google.com', 48.1367075, 11.5556444, 'https://mapbuildr.com/assets/img/markers/solid-pin-green.png']
  ];
  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    if (locations[i][1] == 'undefined') {
      description = '';
    } else {
      description = locations[i][1];
    }
    if (locations[i][2] == 'undefined') {
      telephone = '';
    } else {
      telephone = locations[i][2];
    }
    if (locations[i][3] == 'undefined') {
      email = '';
    } else {
      email = locations[i][3];
    }
    if (locations[i][4] == 'undefined') {
      web = '';
    } else {
      web = locations[i][4];
    }
    if (locations[i][7] == 'undefined') {
      markericon = '';
    } else {
      markericon = locations[i][7];
    }
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      icon: markericon,
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][5], locations[i][6]),
      map: map,
      title: locations[i][0],
      desc: description,
      tel: telephone,
      email: email,
      web: web
    });
    if (web.substring(0, 7) != "http://") {
      link = "http://" + web;
    } else {
      link = web;
    }
    bindInfoWindow(marker, map, locations[i][0], description, telephone, email, web, link);
  }

  function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, title, desc, telephone, email, web, link) {
    var infoWindowVisible = (function() {
      var currentlyVisible = false;
      return function(visible) {
        if (visible !== undefined) {
          currentlyVisible = visible;
        }
        return currentlyVisible;
      };
    }());
    iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      if (infoWindowVisible()) {
        iw.close();
        infoWindowVisible(false);
      } else {
        var html = "<div style='color:#000;background-color:#fff;padding:5px;width:150px;'><h4>" + title + "</h4><p>" + desc + "<p><p>" + telephone + "<p><a href='" + link + "'' >" + web + "<a></div>";
        iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: html
        });
        iw.open(map, marker);
        infoWindowVisible(true);
      }
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(iw, 'closeclick', function() {
      infoWindowVisible(false);
    });
  }
      
      // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(
      document.getElementById('pac-input'));
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(
    /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(input));

  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects an item from the
  // pick list. Retrieve the matching places for that item.
  google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }
    for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    }

    // For each place, get the icon, place name, and location.
    markers = [];
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
      var image = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      };

      // Create a marker for each place.
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location
      });

      markers.push(marker);

      bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
    }

    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });

  // Bias the SearchBox results towards places that are within the bounds of the
  // current map's viewport.
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    searchBox.setBounds(bounds);
  });
}
```

```css
    #restaurantmap {
      height: 400px;
      width: 550px;
    }
    .gm-style-iw * {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .gm-style-iw h4,
    .gm-style-iw p {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .gm-style-iw a {
      color: #4272db;
    }
      .controls {
        margin-top: 16px;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        height: 32px;
        outline: none;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      }

      #pac-input {
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
        width: 400px;
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 300;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
      }

      #pac-input:focus {
        border-color: #4d90fe;
        margin-left: -1px;
        padding-left: 14px;  /* Regular padding-left + 1. */
        width: 401px;
      }

      .pac-container {
        font-family: Roboto;
      }

      #type-selector {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #4d90fe;
        padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
      }

      #type-selector label {
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 300;
      }
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
<div id='restaurantmap'></div>
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
```