# How to use Textarea input for search on a map

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, textarea

I used instructions at https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/ to put a map on my below HTML-File. Similar to [Google Maps Embed + Search box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27826918/google-maps-embed-search-box) I would like to let the user search for an address on the map. Except in my case I'm not using googlemaps and also for the user input I need to use an html input element. So that example didn't really help me.  My code currently looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
<html><head>
//skipping some lines
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <title>Quick Start - Leaflet</title>


    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/docs/images/favicon.ico">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Quick Start - Leaflet_files/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ==" crossorigin="">
    <script src="./Quick Start - Leaflet_files/leaflet.js.Download" integrity="sha512-GffPMF3RvMeYyc1LWMHtK8EbPv0iNZ8/oTtHPx9/cc2ILxQ+u905qIwdpULaqDkyBKgOaB57QTMg7ztg8Jm2Og==" crossorigin=""></script>



</head>
<body>

//skipping Elements

<div id="mapid" style="width: 600px; height: 400px; position: relative; outline: none;" class="leaflet-container leaflet-touch leaflet-fade-anim leaflet-grab leaflet-touch-drag leaflet-touch-zoom" tabindex="0"><div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-map-pane" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);"><div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-tile-pane"><div class="leaflet-layer " style="z-index: 1; opacity: 1;"><div class="leaflet-tile-container leaflet-zoom-animated" style="z-index: 18; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale(1);"><img alt="" role="presentation" src="./Quick Start - Leaflet_files/2723.png" class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(56px, -91px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img alt="" role="presentation" src="./Quick Start - Leaflet_files/2723(1).png" class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(312px, -91px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img alt="" role="presentation" src="./Quick Start - Leaflet_files/2724.png" class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(56px, 165px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img alt="" role="presentation" src="./Quick Start - Leaflet_files/2724(1).png" class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(312px, 165px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img alt="" role="presentation" src="./Quick Start - Leaflet_files/2723(2).png" class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(-200px, -91px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img alt="" role="presentation" src="./Quick Start - Leaflet_files/2723(3).png" class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(568px, -91px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img alt="" role="presentation" src="./Quick Start - Leaflet_files/2724(2).png" class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(-200px, 165px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img alt="" role="presentation" src="./Quick Start - Leaflet_files/2724(3).png" class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(568px, 165px, 0px); opacity: 1;"></div></div></div><div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-shadow-pane"><img src="./Quick Start - Leaflet_files/marker-shadow.png" class="leaflet-marker-shadow leaflet-zoom-animated" alt="" style="margin-left: -12px; margin-top: -41px; width: 41px; height: 41px; transform: translate3d(300px, 247px, 0px);"></div><div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-overlay-pane"><svg pointer-events="none" class="leaflet-zoom-animated" width="720" height="480" viewBox="-60 -40 720 480" style="transform: translate3d(-60px, -40px, 0px);"><g><path class="leaflet-interactive" stroke="red" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="#f03" fill-opacity="0.5" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M141.20355555554852,171.94704600190744a42,42 0 1,0 84,0 a42,42 0 1,0 -84,0 "></path><path class="leaflet-interactive" stroke="#3388ff" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="#3388ff" fill-opacity="0.2" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M358 163L474 219L550 153z"></path></g></svg></div><div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-marker-pane"><img src="./Quick Start - Leaflet_files/marker-icon.png" class="leaflet-marker-icon leaflet-zoom-animated leaflet-interactive" alt="" tabindex="0" style="margin-left: -12px; margin-top: -41px; width: 25px; height: 41px; transform: translate3d(300px, 247px, 0px); z-index: 247;"></div><div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-tooltip-pane"></div><div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-popup-pane"><div class="leaflet-popup  leaflet-zoom-animated" style="opacity: 1; transform: translate3d(301px, 213px, 0px); bottom: -7px; left: -57px;"><div class="leaflet-popup-content-wrapper"><div class="leaflet-popup-content" style="width: 74px;"><b>Hello world!</b><br>I am a popup.</div></div><div class="leaflet-popup-tip-container"><div class="leaflet-popup-tip"></div></div><a class="leaflet-popup-close-button" href="https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/example.html#close">×</a></div></div><div class="leaflet-proxy leaflet-zoom-animated" style="transform: translate3d(1.04805e+06px, 697379px, 0px) scale(4096);"></div></div><div class="leaflet-control-container"><div class="leaflet-top leaflet-left"><div class="leaflet-control-zoom leaflet-bar leaflet-control"><a class="leaflet-control-zoom-in" href="https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/example.html#" title="Zoom in" role="button" aria-label="Zoom in">+</a><a class="leaflet-control-zoom-out" href="https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/example.html#" title="Zoom out" role="button" aria-label="Zoom out">−</a></div></div><div class="leaflet-top leaflet-right"></div><div class="leaflet-bottom leaflet-left"></div><div class="leaflet-bottom leaflet-right"><div class="leaflet-control-attribution leaflet-control"><a href="https://leafletjs.com/" title="A JS library for interactive maps">Leaflet</a> | Map data © <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a></div></div></div></div>
<script>

    var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

    L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
            '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
            'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
        id: 'mapbox.streets'
    }).addTo(mymap);

    L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(mymap)
        .bindPopup("<b>Hello world!</b><br />I am a popup.").openPopup();

    L.circle([51.508, -0.11], 500, {
        color: 'red',
        fillColor: '#f03',
        fillOpacity: 0.5
    }).addTo(mymap).bindPopup("I am a circle.");

    L.polygon([
        [51.509, -0.08],
        [51.503, -0.06],
        [51.51, -0.047]
    ]).addTo(mymap).bindPopup("I am a polygon.");


    var popup = L.popup();

    function onMapClick(e) {
        popup
            .setLatLng(e.latlng)
            .setContent("You clicked the map at " + e.latlng.toString())
            .openOn(mymap);
    }

    mymap.on('click', onMapClick);

</script>
//skipping elements
<div>
<textarea class="longInput" cols="98.5" rows="1" id="OrtTextfield"></textarea></div>


//skipping elements.....


</body></html>
```

How can I bind a textarea element on my HTML-File to an embedded map?

Comment: Look at his repository.  https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search/blob/master/examples/outside.html  There is a div findbox right before the map div.  You add the control as usual as shown in the example.

Comment: @zakariah1, that didn't really help. For some reason, when I save the code in the above link to an html file and open it, l see no maps..

Comment: Your example has "mapid", but the example has "map" as the id.  Could the issue be that simple?

Comment: @zakariah1, i didnt insert his code into mine. l basically saved his code to an html file that l name outside.html. when l click on that html file im expecting to see some kind of map and a search box etc that l could use for my own code. That html-page is however not showing anything. its almost empty.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your links are not valid.  Can you delete your 2 link tags and script tag and use the 2 lines below?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ==" crossorigin="" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-GffPMF3RvMeYyc1LWMHtK8EbPv0iNZ8/oTtHPx9/cc2ILxQ+u905qIwdpULaqDkyBKgOaB57QTMg7ztg8Jm2Og==" crossorigin=""></script>
```

Comment: Mate, that still did't solve my problem. Also, the link you've suggested above uses a .js file called ```labs-common.js``` as src at line 102. Nowhere on his page is this .js file.

Answer (score 0):

can you not just get the input using jquery var userInput = ("#OrtTextfield").html(); 
this would give you the text in the input and store in a variable, then you could have a button with an onClick event to pass the variable in to the map lookup API.

Hope this helps. I've not used the leafletsJS but thats how I would do it for a google map.

Comment: that sounds actually viable. I'm an html/javascript newbie. Hope, you don't mind telling me how I can pass the variable into the map?Where in the above code goes "userInput"  ?